# Поочередное суммирование элементов списка Python

Tags: python

Дан список из чисел A. На выходе необходимо получить список B с суммой всех предыдущих чисел списка A включая число итерируемого индекса.

**Например:**
***На входе:***

```
А=[0,1,2,3,4]
```

***На выходе:***

```
B=[0,1,3,6,10]
```

Comment: `for x in a; s+=x; b.append(s)`

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

```
B = [sum(A[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(A))]
```

**вариант 2:**

```
s = 0
B = [s := s + v for v in A]
```

**вариант 3:**

```
from functools import reduce

B = reduce(lambda r, v: r + [r[-1] + v] if r else [v], A, [])
```

**вариант 4:**

```
B = list(map(lambda v: sum(A[:v[0]]) + v[1], enumerate(A)))
```

или

```
*B, = map(lambda v: sum(A[:v[0]]) + v[1], enumerate(A))
```

**вариант 5:**

```
def func(A):
    return (func(A[:-1]) + [sum(A)]) if A else []

B = func(A)
```

**вариант 6:**

```
from itertools import accumulate

B = list(accumulate(A))
```

или

```
from itertools import accumulate

*B, = accumulate(A)
```

**вариант 7:**

```
import numpy

B = numpy.add.accumulate(A)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам добрый Человек!

Comment: есть и шестой :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `accumulate`:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

A = [0,1,2,3,4]
*B, = accumulate(A)
print(B) # [0,1,3,6,10]
```